# how can i use captcha and audio for human validation?

Tags: php, audio, captcha

I need to validate human user by using captcha in PHP. Also the critical characters generated by captcha will be pronounced by an audio voice. Is it possible? If possible then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) has audio support, and is the easiest way to add captcha to a webapp, including [specific PHP support](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php).